# Memcache Single Pre-written Sql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, memcached

I am using open source software but I need to memcached a certain pre-written sql query for 20 minutes before updating.

Here is a snipit of the file with the MySQL query that needs to be memcached.

How would I change this/what would I add for this query below to be memcached for 20 minutes?

```
if (!empty($forum_ary)){

$sqls = 'SELECT a.attach_id, a.topic_id, a.post_msg_id, a.physical_filename, a.real_filename, f.forum_id, t.topic_id, t.forum_id, t.topic_title
        FROM ' . ATTACHMENTS_TABLE . ' a, ' . FORUMS_TABLE . ' f, ' . TOPICS_TABLE . ' t 
        WHERE (mimetype = "image/jpeg")
        AND f.forum_id = ' . $forum_id . '
        AND a.topic_id = t.topic_id
        AND ' . $db->sql_in_set('t.forum_id', $forum_ary) . '
        AND t.forum_id IN (' . $forums . ')
        ORDER BY post_msg_id DESC';     
$results = $db->sql_query_limit($sqls, $convert_real_size); // NEU Wichtig $convert_real_size
```

Comment: Some code to put it into cache with a 20*60sec timeout would be a good start.

Comment: Yes, but how exactly is that done? The code in OPs question is the code that needs to be cached